# In Javascript are all decimal point numbers odd?

Tags: javascript, math

I wrote this simple function that is working (I think) but I wanted to get feedback to confirm if my assumption is correct.

```
function testingEven(num){
  parseFloat(num);
  if(num % 2 === 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// testingEven(2.4); 
   returns false
```

Does this mean there are infinitely more odd numbers?

Even making the condition number a small even decimal still returns false.

```
function testingEven(num){
  parseFloat(num);
  if(num % .02 === 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

So I guess my question is would a decimal number such as 2.40 be considered odd or even?

Answer (score 2):

An odd number is an **integer** that, when divided by two, leaves a remainder.

So no floating point number (unless it only has `0`s after the point) is odd.

Comment: Ok, for some reason my brain is melting on this.  Are you saying that mathematically `2.00` is odd?  Your second sentence is conflicting with your first one to me.

Comment: @Taplar — 2.00 is an integer, it is just expressed as a floating point number.

Comment: And `2.02`?  It's not an integer, and does return a remainder.

Comment: @quentin so would 2.40 be considered odd or even in JS?

Comment: @Taplar — It is not an integer, so it isn't an odd number.

Comment: @JamesMcCarthy — It is not odd or even in maths. JS is beside the point. JS has no concept of odd or even.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. It makes sense now.